# Cannot resolve custom Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working in .NET Core and have created myself a custom tag helper like so:

```
namespace Phoneden.Web.TagHelpers
{
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

  public class SidebarLink : TagHelper
  {
    private const string ActiveClass = "active";

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-controller")]
    public string Controller { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
      // code omitted
    }
  }
}
```

I then went into the `_ViewImports.cshtml` in `~/Views/` and added the following:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Phoneden.Web
@using Phoneden.Web.Models
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@addTagHelper "*, Phoneden.Web.TagHelpers"
```

But for some reason when I want to use my custom tag helper, Visual Studio draws the squiggly line under it saying it cannot resolve it. I attempt to use it like so:

```
<sidebar-link asp-controller="Supplier" asp-action="Page" icon="work"></sidebar-link>
```

[image: VS error]

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `Phoneden.Web.TagHelpers` an assembly name in this line `@addTagHelper "*, Phoneden.Web.TagHelpers"`? Cause it should be assembly name, not a namespace.

Comment: You likely just need `Phoneden.Web`, not `Phoneden.Web.TagHelpers`. As @Set said, it should be your project (assembly) name, not the full namespace to your taghelper(s). It's admittedly confusing because the Microsoft one includes `TagHelpers`, but that's because that's the actual assembly they're in, i.e. there's a separate project just for Razor TagHelpers in the ASP.NET Core source.